# Spring Data neo4j JUnit4 setup

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, neo4j, junit4, spring-data-neo4j-4

I confess I am a total newbie at the Java way of doing things and I am totally lost trying to get a simple unit test running.

I am building a data access library and want to unit test it. I am using Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT because I need to connect to a remote Neo4j server in the real world.

After battling errors all day I am at the point where I have a test class:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.mystuff.data"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes={Neo4jTestConfiguration.class})
public class PersonRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;
    protected GraphDatabaseService graphDb;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        graphDb = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        graphDb.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreatePerson() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(personRepository);
        Person p = new Person("Test", "User");
        personRepository.save(p);
    }
}
```

Neo4jTestConfiguration.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "org.mystuff.data")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jTestConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory("org.mystuff.data");
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
        // What to return here? I want in-memory database
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return super.getSession();
    }
}
```

When running tests the personRepository.save() throws and exception 'No Scope registered for scope "session"'
I don't know if I need the configuration class but my test class won't work without it because Spring needs @ContextConfiguration and I want all the DI niceness Spring provides (amongst other things).

How can I get my tests to work with Spring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `InProcessServer` which is an in-memory database:

```
@Bean
public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
    return new InProcessServer();
}
```

Omit the session scope as your test isn't running in a web container. An example: https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-cineasts/blob/4.0-RC1/src/test/java/org/neo4j/cineasts/PersistenceContext.java

This will require dependencies as described in this question: [Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0.M1 Test Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245894/spring-data-neo4j-4-0-0-m1-test-configuration)

In your test class `PersonRepositoryTest`, you don't need to construct an instance of the database, your tests will run against the same `InProcessServer`.
Here's an example: https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-cineasts/blob/4.0-RC1/src/test/java/org/neo4j/cineasts/domain/DomainTest.java

Comment: I don't seem to have InProcessServer available. Where does this come from?

Comment: Found it - I needed spring-data-neo4j in my Gradle testCompile definitions

Comment: This works brilliantly now, thank you. The example project is a great source of information and really helps.

Comment: Welcome. There are a couple more sdn4* examples in https://github.com/neo4j-examples